# Validate if the entered text is number

Tags: site-column, validation

Is it possible to write column validation to check if the entered text is number? I have a column named `Year` of type `Single line of text`. I would like to be able to stop the user if he or she enters the text other than number.

By the way, I don't want to have my column as `Number`; this solution t doesn't work for my design.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Column Validation settings (Edit the Column and it is an expandable section near the bottom) you can use this formula:

```
=ISNUMBER([My Column]+0)
```

Just Replace `My Column` with your actual Column's name

Comment: May I know what is the reason of +0?

Comment: I don't know why but it seems to need the +0 (casts it to number?) I tried without the +0 and the column could not validate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sharepoint's column validator.
Check this blog:
http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2011/12/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-column-validation-in-sharepoint-2010/